# Searching string with regex

Tags: windows, cmd

I have some string like

```
something-long-MYCODE-1234-other-things
```

This comes as argument to my .bat so it would be in %1
I would like to get only MYCODE-1234 part. So MYCODE-[0-9]+

I was looking some options in findstr /r but without luck.

Am I able to do such things with cmd?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be impossible: http://blog.staffannoteberg.com/2010/12/02/regex-at-windows-command-line/

I prefer using cmder (http://bliker.github.io/cmder/) a replacement for cmd.